# Problems locale language with converting string to dates

Tags: string, date, locale, date-conversion, chron

I have problems with converting strings into dates. First I encountered the problem and figured out that as.chron is using the Dutch abbrevations. Therefore I thought that changing the locale would solve this problem. However after doing this I still have the same problem and I can not figure out where to adjust the language as.chron uses.

Input

```
require("chron")
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "English")
as.chron("Mrt 12, 2015", format = "%b %e, %Y") #The dutch abbrevation
as.chron("Mar 12, 2015", format = "%b %e, %Y")
```

Output

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","English")
[1] "LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United         States.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United States.1252"
> as.chron("Mrt 12, 2015", format = "%b %e, %Y")
[1] (03/12/15 00:00:00)
> as.chron("Mar 12, 2015", format = "%b %e, %Y") 
[1] (NA NA)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by restarting Rstudio..